# Ajax POST request firing twice for Sequelize.Create in Node.js/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, sequelize.js

No, `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()` do not work. Yes, I'm 100% positive that I'm not clicking the "submit" button twice. No, I'm not going to use `unbind`, because it's 2019.

Now that we have that out of the way:

I have an incredibly simple login/signup sheet that, when the submit button is hit, runs the api POST route twice. Here is the front-end code for the form:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    let timesTriggered = 0;

    $("#signup").on("click", function() {
        timesTriggered++;

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        console.log(timesTriggered); 

        let newUser = {
            username: $("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val()
        };

        $.post("/api/signup", newUser);
    });

});
```

Here is the form itself:

```
<div id = "user-password-field">
        <input id = "username" name = "username" type="text" placeholder = "Username">
        <input id = "password" name = "password" type="password" placeholder = "Password">
        <button id = "login">Login</button>
        <button id="signup">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
```

And here is the api route:

```
let User = require("../models/Users");

module.exports = function(app) {
    let db = require("../models");

    app.post("/api/signup", function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);

        db.User.create({
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));    
    })

}
```

Very simple stuff. And yet, nothing I do (outside of hacking the api route with an iterating variable and an if statement, a short-term solution) makes the route run only once.

Keep in mind, I'm revisiting an area that I'm not especially familiar in: Sequelize. There is a possibility that some sequelize issue is causing the command to be run twice instead of once (although, as I previously mentioned, adding a hack to the api route absolutely did restrict the number of users inserted to one).

For safety, here's the modal folder:

- INDEX.JS

```
"use strict";

var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var basename = path.basename(module.filename);
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
var config = require(__dirname + "/../config/config.json")[env];
var db = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === ".js");
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize["import"](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

- USERS.JS

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    let User = sequelize.define("User", {
        username: DataTypes.STRING,
        password: DataTypes.STRING
    });
    return User;
};
```

And here's the `config.json`:

```
{
    "development": {
      "username": "root",
      "password": none of your business,
      "database": "yar",
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 3306,
      "dialect": "mysql"
    },
    "test": {
      "username": "root",
      "password": none of your business,
      "database": "yar",
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "dialect": "mysql"
    },
    "production": {
      "username": "root",
      "password": null,
      "database": "database_production",
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "dialect": "mysql"
    }
  }
```

And, for good measure, my `server.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();

let db = require("./models");

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.json());

const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
app.engine("handlebars", exphbs({defaultLayout: "main"}));
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");


// Routes
require("./routes/apiRoutes")(app);
require("./routes/htmlRoutes")(app);

db.sequelize.sync().then(function() {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log("Listening in on " + PORT);
    });
});
```

When I looked into the network tab in Google Chrome's inspect tool, it said that the api route "/signup" was run twice. So, while I can imagine that a lack of full understanding of Sequelize might jeopardize me, I'm fairly certain that this is almost completely unrelated to sequelize and is more of an issue with the route, server, and/or ajax call.

Please let me know if you have any answers. I've delved into Google for an hour and found either ridiculously old responses or ones that simply don't work. Best of luck!

**U P D A T E**

[Screenshot of Network Tab][1]

<s>This is a frequently-occurring issue, funnily enough: The ajax call objectively works (the "signup" api route sends the right information directly to the database), and yet, several seconds or minutes after the **successful** post request, Chrome's console will pull up:</s>

`POST http://localhost:3000/api/signup net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

*This issue has been resolved, still seeing the duplicate ajax calls*

Here's another screenshot with a bit more information in the Network Tab:
[More Specific Network Info][2]

**U P D A T E  2**

I've discovered that something called `VM1421` is running alongside my `logic.js` file. No results show up on Google when searching for it (or anything similar). Additionally, the Network tab does have one important difference between the two api calls: One of them is "initiated" by `logicjs`, the other is initiated by `VM1421 logic.js`. The code inside each of these "files" is completely congruent.

Comment: upload network tab screenshot for your api call.

Comment: I've uploaded the screenshot. After roughly seven seconds, the connection will be labeled "Stalled" and the ```EMPTY RESPONSE``` error (mentioned above) will run.

Comment: You're are not sending any response in your route function (or the code you've provided is incomplete). Also, the first request you're seeing is probably an `OPTIONS` request

Comment: Agreed, I should've expected that. Silly mistake. Got the ```EMPTY RESPONSE``` issue immediately fixed, but I'm still experiencing the double-triggered Ajax route. EDIT: I'm not seeing OPTIONS anywhere in the network tab. I'll provide a bit more information in the main post.

Comment: I've setup a minimal app and I'm not able to reproduce your issue. Most likely you're registering the `click` event twice

Comment: Testing with Postman produced only one user in the database (desired result). So, it very well might be registering on click twice. Suggestions on how I would fix that? I've already tried the ```e.stopPropagation```, ```e.stopImmediatePropagation```, and ```e.preventDefault()```, and creating a variable and only running the function if the variable is ```false```, and setting the variable as ```true``` once the function is first run. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned in the first sentence of this post that I'd already used `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` and `e.stopPropagation()`.

Just now, I've gone back into the code and reintroduced `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` and it now works. Because programming.

The only difference I can tell is that I now specify `event` in the onclick function parameters. If you're running into the same problem and have put all three `event` examples, then try getting rid of `e.stopPropagation()` and leaving the other two.